# Ensure that only system DLLs are loaded for the application

Tags: windows, dll

We would like to ensure that when our application is loaded, it uses only Windows system DLLs and not any DLL from the folder containing the exe file for the application. The application is a standalone executable and can be run, for an example, from Download folder, hence the reason for the restriction. Unfortunately one of DLLs is not on KnownDLLs registry setting mentioned in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications).

The same documentation mentioned that one can use exe manifest to control the search order, but it is not clear how to do that to restrict the search path only to system libraries.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/secure-loading-of-libraries-to-prevent-dll-preloading-attacks-d41303ec-0748-9211-f317-2edc819682e1?

Comment: It appears that you can use [/DEPENDENTLOADFLAG:0x800](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dependentloadflag?view=msvc-160) option to specify that only the system32 directory is searched.

Comment: Thanks, this is good at least for Windows 10. I forgot to write in the question that the application needs to support Windows 8. Why it took Microsoft so long to come up with /DEPENDENTLOADFLAG:0x800?

Comment: @GSerg The question is about DLL linked into the executable, not about LoadLibrary usage.